# How can I prevent org-paste-special from merging kill-ring heading and heading on the current line?

Tags: org-mode

I find that org-paste-special more often than not, combines the two headings, like

```
** one ** two
```

, instead of

```
*** one
*** two
```

, so I always have to correct it, after a paste.

Is there any way to modify this command, so that it doesn't merge the kill-buffer and the heading on the current line?;)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: can you describe the initial state, what subtree you have in your kill-ring and where exactly you do `C-c C-x C-y`? Also, what version of Org mode you are running? I tested with recent upstream with no problem, but your version may be buggy.